# Is it possible to read actual applied immutable policy on a blob - remaining Time-based retention in days

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I have applied a Time-based retention e.g. 5 days. Is it possible to read on each blob / their metadata, when this policy is expiring...

Same way as we can read on soft deleted blobs RemainingRetentionDays??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `Time-based immutable policy`, there is no direct way to know when this policy is expiring. You need to calculate it by yourself. For example, if the Time-based retention is 5-days, then you upload a blob in `January 1`. Then in January 2, it has 4-days to be expired.

For `soft deleted blobs`, yes, you can read the `RemainingRetentionDays` by using code or using UI.

Here is an example to read this value via UI, you should install [Azure Storage Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-manage-with-storage-explorer?tabs=windows#download-and-install). Then you can see the `RemainingRetentionDays` for each deleted blobs(Note: due to [this bug](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/16268), you should **turn off** versioning feature.):

[image]

Comment: ok, I was hoping that I did not have to calc it myself for "Time-based immutable policy", but trust metadata from MS.